# An interesting thing about overriding linux kernel macro

Tags: c, linux

In the following code, it is compiled success and print 1024

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FD_SETSIZE 512
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", FD_SETSIZE);
}
```

But in the following code, it is compiled failed and print

`test.c:4:1: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:220,
                 from test_fd.c:3:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:81:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition`

the code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define FD_SETSIZE 512

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", FD_SETSIZE);
}
```

Can anbody explain this? Thanks!

Comment: there are endless numbers of different ways to hurt yourself when fiddling with the limitations of `select()`. Rather use `poll()` instead.

Comment: @mfro,  this question has nothing to do with using `select()`.

Comment: I guess it has. Why would you want to change FD_SETSIZE if not because to overcome long-standing `select()` limitations?

Answer (score 1):

But in the following code, it is compiled failed and print

In the question, both the programs were compiled, but while compiling first program you got warnings in preprocessor stage.

Preprocessor stage is responsible for the replacement of macros.

In this example the preprocessor is using the last defined macro and replacing it.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#define  FD_SETSIZE 512
#include  <sys/types.h>
```

Here the definition of FD_SETSIZE is there in both the .c file and also in header file sys/types.h.
After the file inclusion, then the replacing of  macros will be done,so the latest defined macro is replaced.

So the final replacement FD_SETSIZE of will be same as defined in the sys/types.h file and vice-versa.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: or course, you really want to write code that cleanly compiles.  This means fixing that warning about a duplicate definition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [#undef directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4w8783.aspx) to remove the defined macro and replace it later

```
#ifdef MACRO
#undef MACRO
#endif

#define MACRO
```